# Android. Show fullscreen content (activity?!) while device is closed

Tags: android

When I receive a push notification I need to be able to display a fullscreen message/notification to the user with two buttons with which he can interact.

Something similar to how Skype/Whatsapp does it when receiving a call. I need to wake up the phone, make the display light up, and then show this fullscreen notification (Activity ?!) and wait for the user to interact with it. Have a positive and negative button on the screen, and then make an API call after the user chooses one, and then close the fullscreen activity or whatever it would be.

What would be the best approach for this, considering I need to have it work on Oreo as well.

Comment: I think the behaviour you described of the 3rd partys are an API only for handling calls, don't think other action is available, else I think you can work something with WAKE_UP permission, but that will not override the lockscreen

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but I thought I'd ask. I wonder if I trick the system a bit, "simulate" an incoming call and display my own layout to the user...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you just need to start an activity after you have received the push notification. In order to satisfy your needs, the activity needs to be configured accordingly:

In order to show an activity over a possible lock screen which can be active if a device is "closed":

- for API 27+: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setShowWhenLocked(boolean)
- for older APIs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

In order to wake up the screen when the activity is about to be displayed:

- for API 27+: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTurnScreenOn(boolean)
- for older APIs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON